# SQL query for operation between rows under some condition

Tags: mysql, postgresql

Its little complicated query as it contains some conditions.

I have tables like this:

```
table DC - which contains one row for one northing-easting pair
Columns   -       Id    Northing    Easting 
PossibleValues - Guid   Std value   Std value

table DCR - which contains multiple rows for each row in DC. Each row here corresponds to data on each pass on that exact location.
Columns -         Id    VibStatus        DrivingDir          CompactionValue    UtcDate
PossibleValues - Guid     0/1     Forward/Reverse/Neutral    +ve integers      Timestamp

table DCMappings - which contains mapping between both tables.
DCId    DCRId
```

The output I need should contain fields like this:

```
ResultTable
DCId    DCRId    Northing    Easting    VibStatus    DrivingDir    CompValue    Position    CompProgress
```

Here, Position is its position in chronological order when sorted by UtcDate grouped by DC.Id(See query at end to understand more).

And CompProgress has some conditions which is making it complicated.

CompProgress is percentage increase/decrease in CompValue compared to its previous row which was in same driving direction when arranged in ASC order of UtcDate(chronological) where the rows to be considered here should only be the ones with VibStatus set to ON(1) grouped by DCId's.

Each row in DC has multiple rows in DCR. So if row 1 in DC has 10 rows in DCR, the CompProgress should consider these 10 rows alone for calculation and then for row 2 in DC, etc...

I have written following query to extract needed fields except calculation of CompProgress. Please help me in this.

```
SELECT DC.Id, DCR.Id, Northing, Easting, VibStatus, DrivingDir, CompValue, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION By dcm."DCId" ORDER BY dcr."UtcDate") as passNo
FROM "DCR" dcr  LEFT JOIN "DCMappings" dcm ON "Id" = dcm."DCRId"
                LEFT JOIN "DC" dc ON dc."Id" = dcm."DCId"
```

Need evaluation of CompProgress in this query.

Sorry for lot of text. But it was necessary to make others understand what is needed.

Comment: This is hard to understand. As I understand it: DC is basically (X,Y) coordinartes + DCR is a trajectory over these waypoints? CompProgress is totally unclear to me, should it be a delta wrt the previous waypoint?

Comment: @wildplasser: No its completely different domain than what you are talking about. This is more into compaction. There are many other columns in the table. But just for simplification, I have given only these columns.
As I said above, CompProgress is percentage increase. Lets say row 1 has comp value 100, row 2 has comp value 150, row 3 has comp value 225. Then CompProgress for row 1 to be blank as it doesnt have any previous rows. Row 2's compProgress will be (150-100)/100*100 = 50%. Row 3's compProgress will be (225-150)/150*100 = 50%. 
This is what I want to achieve. Hope this detail helps.

Comment: So the DC.{Nothing,Easting} are irrelevant for the calculation. Maybe you should add some test data (+ real DDL) to your question. +intended result.

Comment: Thats irrelavant for the calculation. But thats needed for the end table. Hence, i have to joined the tables. And to show that i have added it here. I will add the test data very soon.